# What is the easiest way to calculate total price and quantities for multiple items in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a number of inputs such as:

```
<input type="number" name="qty[]" data-price="123.99" value="0" class="qtyfield" min="0">
<input type="number" name="qty[]" data-price="222.11" value="0" class="qtyfield" min="0">
<input type="number" name="qty[]" data-price="25.68" value="0" class="qtyfield" min="0">
```

if someone selects a quantity from the first one of 6 and the second example of quantity of 8 I need a running total to be calculated as any changes occur.

Comment: Firstly have a go yourself! That's the best option.

Comment: `.querySelectorAll()`, `for`, `parseFloat()`, `.addEventListener()`

Comment: `$`, `.on()`, `.each()`, `.data()`

Comment: evolutionbox: I already had, which is why I asked here. did not think of using map, which worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the point here is to get running total of your quantities, weighted by `data-price` value, you may simply listen for changes and update result value with `reduce()`'ed sum of input field multiplied by `data-price`:

```js
$('.qtyfield').on('change', () => {
   const total = [...$('.qtyfield')]
    .map(input => $(input).val()*$(input).attr('data-price'))
    .reduce((t,q) => t+q,0)
   $('#result').text(total)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" name="qty[]" data-price="1" value="0" class="qtyfield" min="0">
<input type="number" name="qty[]" data-price="2" value="0" class="qtyfield" min="0">
<input type="number" name="qty[]" data-price="3" value="0" class="qtyfield" min="0">
<div id="result"></div>
```

**Note:** I have changed `data-price` values for simplicity sake